# Resolving `Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled` - React + Express + Webpack + Babel

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, babel-loader

I have read through similar responses, but haven't been able to track down my specific issue based off those questions / answers, so I apologize in advance for the oft repeated question.

I am running an express server on AWS EB that hosts a React app. However, I'm currently using universal routing, and want to switch to isomorphic routing / server side rendering for SEO purposes. I followed [this guide](https://medium.com/@wlto/how-to-deploy-an-express-application-with-react-front-end-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-880ff7245008) to get my initial express app hosting a React front end, and it worked great!

Then I tried to use [this guide](https://medium.com/@phoebe.greig/headache-free-isomorphic-app-tutorial-react-js-react-router-node-js-ssr-with-state-and-es6-797a8d8e493a) to add server side rendering.

My error is:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /express-app/client/src/index.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (13:5):
Add @babel/preset-react (https://git.io/JfeDR) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
```

Here is my file structure:

```
express-app/
- package.json
- server.js
- router.js
- routes.js
- renderFullPage.js
- .babelrc
- webpack.config.js
- client/ // This houses the React app
-- package.json
-- src/
--- index.js
--- app.js
--- // Other component sources
-- build/
--- Output from `npm run build-web`
```

Initially the express app was basically just the single server.js used to serve the client build.

**express-app/.babelrc:**

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ]
}
```

Previously, this did not include the "@babel/preset-react" line.

**express-app/webpack.config.js:**

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    devtool: 'inline-source-map',
    entry: ['./client/src/index.js'],  
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                include: path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'src'),
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                /*query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }*/
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Notable here is that the guide I followed had module.loaders instead of module.rules, since the guide was older. First I changed loaders to rules, and then it complained about the query, so I commented that out.

**express-app/package.json**:

```
{
  "name": "redacted",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "redacted",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon --exec babel-node server.js --ignore client",
    "build": "babel server.js --out-file server.compiled.js",
    "build:client": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.js/",
    "build:prod": "npm run build && npm run build:client"
  },
  "author": "redacted",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "node-jsx": "^0.13.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/core": "^7.13.10",
    "@babel/node": "^7.13.12",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.13.12",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^5.28.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.5.0"
  }
}
```

In the previous implementation, the scripts section did not include the build:client or build:prod lines.  I would run `npm run build-web` in the `client/` folder, which created my build folder, and then I'd run `npm run build` from the top level folder, which would create my compiled server.js file. I would then upload this to EB and be good to go! `devDependencies` are the same except everything below `nodemon` are new after following the second guide.

**express-app/client/package.json:**

```
{
    "name": "redacted",
    "main": "./App.js",
    "engines": {
        "node": "12.21.0",
        "npm": "6.14.11"
    },
    // ...
    "dependencies": {
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-art": "^16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-native": "^0.63.4",
        "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
        "react-native-web": "^0.15.0",
        "react-native-webview": "^11.3.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
        "request": "^2.88.2",
        "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start-web": "react-scripts start",
        "build-web": "react-scripts build",
        "test-web": "react-scripts test",
        "eject-web": "react-scripts eject",
        "start:prod": "NODE_ENV=production node build/index.js",
        "eb:prod": "npm run build-web && npm run start:prod"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.13",
        "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source": "^6.22.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-expo": "^8.3.0",
        "eslint": "^7.22.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0"
    }
}
```

Cut out what I believe to be bloat from this file for you. This file is currently untouched, but from some of the other similar questions/answers, I tried changing `"main": "./App.js",` to use `./build/App.js`, to no avail.

Here is my **express-app/server.js**

```
//Server.js

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
import router from './router';

const PORT = process.env.HTTP_PORT || 4001;
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build')));


// Old routing before using isomorphic
/*
app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'));
});
*/

// Now using router.js for isomorphic handling
app.get('*', router);


app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening at port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

I left the commented previous version so you can see how my code changed.

**express-app/router.js:**

```
import {renderToString} from 'react-dom/server';
import React from 'react';
import {matchPath, StaticRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import routes from './routes';
import renderFullPage from './renderFullPage';
import App from './client/src/app';

export default function router(req, res) {
    const match = routes.reduce((acc, route) => matchPath(req.url, {path: route, exact: true}) || acc, null);

    if( !match ){
        res.status(404).send('page not found :(');
        return;
    }

    const context = {};
    const html = renderToString(
        <StaticRouter context={context} location={req.url} >
            <App />
        </StaticRouter>
    );
    
    res.status(200).send(renderFullPage(html));

};
```

I note that the path to App is `./client/src/app`, so this could be *an* issue, but doesn't seem to be *the* issue, since it's index.js getting dinged.

**express-app/client/src/index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';




// For isomorphic handling
ReactDOM.render((
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
    </BrowserRouter>), document.getElementById('root')
);

// This was used prior to isomorphic handling
/*
ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
*/
```

Again I left the old code commented out in there for comparison. This is where my error is stemming from. The error is thrown on the `BrowserRouter` line.

I'm rather stuck on how to resolve this without breaking stuff. Do I need to restructure my whole app? Basically change the compartmentalization I have going on with the client directory? Is there some dumb one liner I'm missing? Any help is *extraordinarily* appreciated!

Comment: My 2 cents, rename `.babelrc` to `babel.config.json` as the latter is project-wide, see https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files for more. Then update those babel plugins and presets defined in your `package.json`, avoid those beginning with `babel-plugin` or `babel-preset` as they're sort of outdated now, use `@babel/xxx` instead.

Comment: Thank you very much, @chenxsan! Not really sure why, but renaming `.babelrc` to `babel.config.json` fixed the problem for me :) I spent so many hours trying plenty of different possible solutions that I found on the internet, can't believe that's all I needed to do xP

Comment: Out of curiosity, @RodrigoD'Agostino, are you using React or React Native? My issue seemed to come from the fact I was trying to do server side rendering for a *React Native* app instead of just React, which instead required thee use of Next.js. Which in hindsight, looking at this question, seems I misspoke multiple times referencing React instead of React Native.

Comment: @JakeT. just pure and simple React. No React Native or Next JS in my project.

Comment: @chenxsan Your recommendation to rename the file fixed my project. Thank you so much!